# Active a button when at least a row is selected

Tags: jquery, datatable

i've a DataTables table in my web page, and i would like to create some buttons that activate when one or more rows are selected.

With DataTables built in function when i select a class SELECTED is  added to the element. How can i use this class with jquery for activate a button?

Thanks